# How to increase expiry time of cache in AFNetworking for iOS

Tags: ios, caching, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I need to download and show images in cell and i am using

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
```

method for that but after sometime downloaded images disappears from cells and downloads again. I found that image can be kept in cache for 30 secs only but I want to save it in cache forever and want to remove cache manually by calling the function to release the cache. Is it possible?

Comment: This is possible yes. But it requires you to store it on your phone and retrieve it from there whenever you need it. Btw, the title of your question is pretty confusing considering your question. You might want to change it.

Comment: But is there any method present in AFNetworking API?

Comment: Are you setting image in table view cell?

Comment: No, you gotta write that yourself (and it's not really hard to do so).

Comment: @TotumusMaximus But in that case, I will have to remove whole code of AFNetworking and I am at the closure of my app. That change will be time taking for me. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Not really. AFNetworking is meant to retrieve data from internet. It's not his responsibility to store/cache it for you during your app lifetime. You can keep the AFNetworking lib, you just need to add the caching/storing part of your files yourself. And when you want to show the image you just check if its in the cache first and if not then ask the AFNetworking API to lazy load it (and then cache/store it. I can give you the bit of code where you can store files if you want. This bit of code will permanently store the files tho.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus OK, please share the code.

Comment: AFNetworking internally does caching. No need to do your self. Check it in UIImage extension .m file.

Comment: @rajath I know that! See my question as I have mentioned the issue in that "image can be kept in cache for 30secs" in cache.

Comment: @Developer I've posted my way of storage. Have a look, it's quite complete.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) check the server headers for the caching policy of the server to store your images. Also make sure that you cache is large enough to store the images. If the images size is large then 5% (or something) then the cache size the images is not cached.

Since [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) uses the default [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) your best option is to subclass [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html). With you custom version of [`NSURLCache`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLCache_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you can then check if the request is an image, if so store it for the time you want some where in the `caches` directory.

This way you can keep using [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)  as you are used to./

Comment: I think that AFNetworking already doing but don't know where it stores the image. See this--------------- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url
       placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request addValue:@"image/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];------------

Comment: All `NSURLConnection`/`NSURLSession` use `NSURLCachce`. Since AFNetworking is build on top of `NSURLConnection`/`NSURLSession` they use `NSURLCache`. Thus if you cache is too small not images will be cached. If you want images to be cached longer then the server headers tell `NSURLCache` they should be cached you will have to write your own version of `NSURLCache`.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to deal with files permanently when you retrieve it with AFNetworking is using the following methods:

```
//Store the file
+ (void) cacheFile:(NSString *)fileName data:(NSData *)data
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName]; //add our image to the path
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL ok = [fileManager createFileAtPath:fullPath contents:data attributes:nil];

    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", fullPath);
    } else {
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fullPath];
        [myFileHandle writeData:data];
        [myFileHandle closeFile];
    }
}

//Check if file is already stored
+ (BOOL) fileExistsInCache:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    DLog(@"path to file's existance, %@", fullPath);

    return [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:fullPath];
}

//Load file from storage
+ (NSData *) loadCachedFile:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    DLog(@"path to file's existance, %@", fullPath);

    NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:fullPath];
    return [myFileHandle readDataToEndOfFile];
}

//Remove file from storage
+ (void) removeCachedFile:(NSString *)fileName
{   
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:NULL];
}

//Find out what is already stored
+ (NSMutableArray *)returnAllCachedMediaFiles
{
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];

    DLog(@"dirContents %@", dirContents);

    NSMutableArray *cachedMediaFiles = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    for (NSString *fileName in dirContents) 
    {
        if ([fileName hasSuffix:@".png"] || [fileName hasSuffix:@".jpg"]) 
        {
            [cachedMediaFiles addObject:fileName];
        }
    }

    return cachedMediaFiles;
}
```

The correct placements within your project I cannot say. However these methods will give you enough handles to work with.
Keep in mind that the documentsDirectory is used and you might want to use something of your own (like the NSCachesDirectory or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Here simple method to get image

```
- (void) cacheImage: (NSString *) ImageURLString
{
assert(nil != ImageURLString);

NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * fileName = [ImageURLString lastPathComponent];
NSString * uniquePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
// Check for file existence
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: uniquePath])
{
    // Fetch image from url and cache it
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:ImageURLString]];
    [data writeToFile:uniquePath atomically:YES];
}

}

- (UIImage *) getCachedImage: (NSString *) ImageURLString
{
assert(nil != ImageURLString);

// create unique path for image
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath    = [myPathList  objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * fileName = [ImageURLString lastPathComponent];
NSString * uniquePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

UIImage *image;

// Check for a cached version
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: uniquePath])
{
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath]; //this is the cached image
}
else
{
    // cache image and return cached image
    [self cacheImage: ImageURLString];
    image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: uniquePath];
}

return image;
}
```

By calling second method you can get cached image, If it is not cached it will get from URL and store it in file and return image to you. I am not implemented cleaning code for it.